# How to create rakefile for ra10ke

Tags: ruby, puppet, rakefile, r10k

I need assistance in creating a Rakefile to implement Ra10ke. [Ra10ke](https://github.com/voxpupuli/ra10ke) is a tool that performs checks on the Puppetfile to ensure correctness, including syntax, deprecated modules, dependencies, etc.

I have never used or compiled a Rakefile before, and I am unsure how to proceed with its implementation. I would need this tasks 'r10k:syntax', 'r10k:dependencies', 'r10k:solve_dependencies', 'r10k:install', 'r10k:validate' and 'r10k:deprecation'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [usage section](https://github.com/voxpupuli/ra10ke?tab=readme-ov-file#usage)

Add the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ra10ke'
```

Add the following lines in your Rakefile:

```
require 'ra10ke'
Ra10ke::RakeTask.new
```